# Is Android log output visible for apps downloaded from the Play store?

Tags: android, security, logcat

Are there (maybe hidden) techniques which allow to see all log messages emitted from an downloaded app, if I have the device connected to my computer over USB (and running Android Studio)?

If yes, this clearly means that log output should carefully checked before release, so that they do no reveal anything such as full web URLs to production system resources etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, log messages are visible from apps downloaded from the Play Store, and you're right; this is a security issue. Viewing the logs from a downloaded app is as simple as plugging in the phone and running `adb logcat`.

Consequently, you'll want to use a library like [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber), which allows you to only log in debug mode, or alternatively use ProGuard to strip out all logs at compile time:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

It's worth noting that logging also impacts your app's performance a little, so it's worth disabling/removing all logging in production anyway just for that.

Comment: That's not a security leak, at least, if App's developer did have enough experience to **not** log sensitive info.

Comment: Even if that's a security-leak for some poorly-programmed App, your own App's info leaks into your own ADB (wanna hack your own bank-account?). Also, it seems Apps can not access each other's logs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes all log are visible in output if you write code for log.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when building for release you should not include any logs that output any sensitive data